# add a constant to a specified column of a matrix for a cell array in matlab

Tags: matlab, cell-array

Assume I have a `4x1` cell array,`A`, inside each cell is a `2x5` matrix,

```
A={[1 1 1 1 1; 2 2 2 2 2];
   [3 3 3 3 3; 4 4 4 4 4];
   [5 5 5 5 5; 6 6 6 6 6];
   [7 7 7 7 7; 8 8 8 8 8]}
```

what I want is to add a constant,let's say `100`, to the `4th` column of matrix for each cell to make `B`. For example

```
B={[ 1 1 1 101 1; 2 2 2 102 2];
   [3 3 3 103 3; 4 4 4 104 4];
   [5 5 5 105 5; 6 6 6 106 6];
   [7 7 7 107 7; 8 8 8 108 8]}
```

What is the best way to do it?

I can get the addition result by using

```
B=cellfun(@(x) x(:,4)+100,A,'uni',0)
```

but have difficult to  get B. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can guarantee that the matrix in cell in `A` is of the same dimensions (in your case, a 2x5 matrix), you can concatenate all matrices vertically:

```
B = cat(1, A{:});
```

then add 100 to the fourth column:

```
B(:, 4) = B(:, 4) + 100;
```

and then convert back it back to a cell array:

```
B = mat2cell(B, size(A{1}, 1) * ones(size(A)), size(A{1}, 2));
```

In this case consider representing the data as a three-dimensional matrix instead of a cell array. It would be much easier to manipulate.

In the general case, you would employ a `for` loop:

```
B = A;
for k = 1:numel(A)
    B{k}(:, 4) = B{k}(:, 4) + 100;
end
```

Comment: @ EitanT, thanks for the fast reply, what will you suggest if the length (number of rows) of the matrix inside of each cell are different ??

Comment: @Tai-YenChen As I've already mentioned in the answer, use a `for` loop. It's not as a slow as you'd expect... :)

Comment: @ EithanT, I did not see the information about the for loop in the answer before my post, XD. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a matrix to each cell as shown below:

```
B=cellfun(@(x) x+[0 0 0 100 0;0 0 0 100 0],A,'UniformOutput',false);
```